# all prime numbers have irrational square roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that all prime numbers have irrational square roots?

My work so far: suppose that a prime p = a*a then p is divisible by a. Contradiction. Did I begin correctly? How to continue?

Comment: The work so far is not correct. You need to suppose that $p=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers (with naturally $b\ne 0$). Probably you will also want to say that without loss of generality $a$ and $b$ have no common factor greater than $1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard proof for $p=2$ works for any prime number.

Comment: How (I see that it does, but why formally does that work?)

Comment: @AlecTeal Because $p\mid a^2\implies p\mid a $ for $p$ a prime.

Comment: Sure, just so simply write up infinitely many proofs....

Comment: @Adam What...? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think Adam should write up infinitely many proofs -- he might learn something.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I (mistakenly) thought that Igor is suggesting to prove the result for every prime number separately....

Comment: @Adam I am glad you figured things out.

Answer (score 5):

Note that this answer is included only so it is clear what Igor Rivin meant by standard proof:

$$\sqrt p = \frac a b$$
where $a$ and $b$ are co-prime (the fraction is reduced) and $p$ is prime.
$$b^2 p = a^2$$
as $a^2$ must disible by $p$ means $a$ must be divisible by $p$
$$b^2 = p c^2$$
where $c=\frac p a$

This will result in the fact that $b$ must also be divisble by $p$ which is a contraction of the fact that $a$ and $b$ are co-prime.

Please try this with $p = 4$ and see where is breaks down.

Comment: We assumed what?

Comment: @kaine I misread something. I apologize. =)

Comment: Adam, the assumptions are that p is prime and the $\frac a b$ is in it's simplist form, aka it cannot be $\frac 4 2$ as that would reduce to $\frac 2 1$.

Comment: I think Kaine's proof is correct.

Comment: @Adam you should probably accept Mr. Rivin answer then, my answer is just clarification of his in case it was not clear what he meant.

Comment: Alternately use RRT on $x^2-p$.

Comment: What does RRT mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly_exploring_random_tree

Comment: @kaine ah, that explains it :)

Comment: Hmm not sure if the above is sarcasm, but I meant Rational Root Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$p=a^2/b^2\implies a^2=pb^2$.  The number of prime factors of $a^2$ is even whereas the numbers of prime factors of $ pb^2$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt only shows that the square root of a prime is not an *integer*.

Comment: I am aware of the fact.